# (Scheme) Find out if some of the numbers in a list add up to a certain number?

Tags: list, scheme

I'm making a program that takes a list and a sum. If some of the numbers in the list add up to the sum, it returns true. Else, return false. It seems to be working for some cases but not for others. For example,

if I input this:

```
(numlist-sum '(5 9) 9)
```

It should return true because one of the numbers (9) equals the sum (9). But, for some reason, its returning false.

I can't figure out what the problem is. Help please?

```
(define (numlist-sum? ls sum)
  (if (null? ls) #t
    (if (and (null? (cdr ls)) (equal? (car ls) sum)) #t
      (if (equal? (car ls) sum) #t
          (if (equal? (cdr ls) sum) #t
              (if (equal? (apply + (car ls) (cdr ls)) sum) #t
                  #f))))))
```

Comment: Don't forget to post the code for `numlist-sum` that you've written so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give you some hints for solving this problem (looks like homework). First write a procedure that generates all the possible subsets of the list (e.g., the [power set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of the list). For example:

```
(powerset '(1 2 3))
=> '(() (1) (2) (3) (1 2) (1 3) (2 3) (1 2 3))
```

With the above procedure in hand (and it's easy to find the algorithm, Google is your best friend), simply iterate over each of the sublists and sum its values:

```
(apply + '(2 3))
=> 5
```

If one of the sublists' sum equals the expected value, return `#t`. If none of the sums satisfy the expected value, return `#f`.

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention, this is a well-known problem - it's the [subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), which can be efficiently solved (at least, more efficiently than generating the power set) using [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). But I don't think that's the goal of this homework in particular.

Comment: Ok, so if the sum isn't equal to the first sublist, how do I move it to the next one? Should I use recursion or apply?

Comment: @taylor18 advance recursively to the next one, just traverse the list of sublists, testing each element in turn until you find what you're looking for.

Comment: i know this isn't right but am i on the right track?

    (define (numlist-sum ls sum)
      (cond
    [(null? ls) '()]
    [(equal? (caar (powerset ls)) sum) #t ]
    [else (numlist-sum ((cadr (powerset ls)) sum))]))

Comment: Not quite. Here we're dealing with a list whose items are sublists, you don't have to actually _extract_ their elements, just add them and compare the sum. Hence this is wrong: `(caar (powerset ls))`. And this is wrong, too (why calculate the power set each time?): `(cadr (powerset ls))`. Create two procedures, one that calculates the power set only _once_, and pass the resulting list to the other. Then advance, one sublist at a time

Comment: Also, remember that at some point you'll have to return `#f`, where is that happening? You need to work hard and start solving the problems on your own, once the power set procedure is in place the rest should be very simple by now. Now you see the importance of solving the problems on your own, it's pointless if someone else solves them for you here in Stack Overflow.

Comment: Ok, i'll figure it out. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that checks each element one by one and then recurses down the list if the first element isn't the sum.

```
(define (numlist-sum list sum)
  (and (not (null? list))
       (let ((head (car list)))
         (cond ((number? head)
                (or (= sum head)
                    (numlist-sum (cdr list) sum)))
               ((list? head)
                (or (= sum (apply + head))
                    (numlist-sum (cdr list) sum)))
               (else 'ill-formed-list)))))
```

Also, note that your code can be rewritten as:

```
(define (numlist-sum? ls sum)
  (or (null? ls)
      (if (and (null? (cdr ls)) (equal? (car ls) sum))
      (equal? (car ls) sum)
      (equal? (cdr ls) sum)
      (equal? (apply + (car ls) (cdr ls)) sum)))
```

I'd say the use of '(if pred #t else ...) is a bit awkward and hides the true logic of the code.